# Filter the first group after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

Sometimes it is handy to take a test case out of your data when working with `group_by()` from the `dplyr` library. I was wondering if there is any fast way to just grab the first group of a grouped dataframe and cast it to a new dataframe.

All I could come up with was this workaround:

```
library(dplyr)
smalldf <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% group_split(.) %>% .[[1]]
```

Comment: `group_split(mtcars,gear)[[1]]` , although that is not really any different than what you are doing

Comment: Or just `split(mtcars, mtcars$gear)[[1]]`

Comment: Or.... dont use split `mtcars[mtcars$gear == unique(mtcars$gear)[1],]`.